# How to get certificate serveruri in azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I'm using a pipeline to deploy function app to azure, in my code I have to use certificate server uri(key vault reference in config file) to get permission.How can I get the Secret Identifier value as a variable when deploy to app services.I just want to deploy this variable from keyvault in pipeline automatically.
Here I'm using Azure keyvault Task:

```
  steps:
    - task: AzureKeyVault@1
      displayName: 'Azure Key Vault: KV-Secrets-Dev'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'Azure: DEV'
        KeyVaultName: 'KV-Secrets-Dev'
```

and them deploy funtion app with appsettings:

```
-clientCertificatePfx @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=$(spdevpfx))
```

here I can get the certtificate valut from $(spdevpfx),but I just want it as a server URI,how to get it?

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to get the Secret URI with Azure KeyVault Task in Azure DevOps. Explained in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops):

> Use this task in a build or release pipeline to download secrets such
>   as authentication keys, storage account keys, data encryption keys,
>   .PFX files, and passwords from an Azure Key Vault instance. The task
>   can be used to fetch the latest values of all or a subset of secrets
>   from the vault, and set them as variables that can be used in
>   subsequent tasks of a pipeline.

---

**Workaround**

You may use the Azure PowerShell task to get the id of your secret. And then pass it to the next task by [setting it to an environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-job-scoped-variable-from-a-script).